# Any comparasion condition returns bad value

Tags: java, object, comparison

I struggle with very strange behaviour while trying to compare two ints but first things first. Here is my method inside the class:

```java
public class CollectionsTutorial {
    private Collection<String> collection = null;
    
    public CollectionsTutorial() {
        this.collection = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
            collection.add("item_"+((i+1)%10000));
        }
    }
    
    public Set<String> getSet(){
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(10000);
        for(String item: this.collection) {
            if (!set.contains(item)) {
                set.add(item);
            }
        }
        return set;
    }

    public TreeSet<String> getEvery3ElementAsSortedSet(){
        TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<String>();
        int counter = 0;
        for(String item : this.collection) {
            if (counter%2==0) {
                tree.add(item);
                counter = -1;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        return tree;
    }
}
```

The whole class doesn't really matter here - it only holds `ArrayList<String>`. I need to return every 3rd element in a tree and everything goes well until it's time to compare current counter value. It returns true everytime. I'm sure of it becouse while testing it's adding to the Tree every single element of collection. I've tried using `compareTo()`, `equalsTo()`, `valueOf()` and `intValue()` but nothing helps.

EDIT.
I've change code to the class view - maybe something else is cousing the error?

Here is test i'm trying to pass

```java
public class CollectionsTutorialTest {

    @Test
    public void GetEvery3ElementTest() {
        CollectionsTutorial testObj = new CollectionsTutorial();
        TreeSet<String> tree = new TreeSet<String>();
        tree.addAll(testObj.getSet() );
        assertEquals(false, tree.contains("item_2"));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Then you post a question, then always make sure that the code reproduces the issue. Your current code doesn't: https://ideone.com/djcU3j

Comment: If you're just trying to get every third item, then why not use an index loop which is perfect for non-sequential index incrementing? `for(int i = 2; i < this.collection.size(); i += 3) { tree.add(this.collection.get(i)); }`

Comment: @user15793316 Nvm. Actually now come to think of it. I don't see the point of this condition. What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @user15793316 I know what the code is doing. I am asking why is it even needed. If user want to add value from specific index there are better ways of doing it. Also, you are not OP. Where did OP go?

Comment: @Goion *"What is the purpose of it?"* ... OP already wrote that: *I need to return every 3rd element*.

Comment: @user15793316 already done and doesn't work, and yep, it works fine for me except that this condition is always true. I'll edit post in a sec

Comment: @user15793316 already fixed - it was a mix of modulo stupid inattention and even more while testing - I was adding to ```tree``` elements from bad method - ```getSet()``` instead ```getEvery3ElementAsSortedSet()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need to return every 3rd element in a tree..." this description screams for the [modulo `%` operator](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic).

If you want to enter an if-condition on every 3rd iteration then you can check this with the following condition: `counter % 3 == 0`. You don't need to subtract anything at all.

**How does `%` work?**

Put simply: The modulo operator returns the result of a division.

Example:

```
5 / 3 = 1 with remain 2
5 % 3 = 2 

9 / 3 = 3 with remain 0 
9 % 3 = 0
```

---

*Note:*

```java
if (counter % 2 == 0) {
    tree.add(item);
    counter = -1;
}
counter++;
```

You use `counter % 2 == 0`. This will return `true` for the second element. Afterwards you set `counter = -1` because you intend to get every 3rd element. However, this does not work.

Here's the reason why:

```
System.out.println(0 % 1);        // 0 % 1 = 0
System.out.println(0 % 2);        // 0 % 2 = 0
System.out.println(0 % 3);        // 0 % 3 = 0
System.out.println(0 % 4);        // 0 % 4 = 0
```

As you can see, every time your `counter` reaches the value `0` the if-condition will result in true regardless of the divisor. That's why you use `% 3`.

Comment: It doesn't work either, I've tried this already :(

Answer (score 0):

the list is created by:

```
        for(int i=0;i<100_000;i++) {
            collection.add("item_"+((i+1)%10_000));
        }
```

resulting in:

> ```
>    collection[0] = item_1
>    collection[1] = item_2
>    collection[2] = item_3
>    collection[3] = item_4
>    ...
>    collection[9_998] = item_9999
>    collection[9_999] = item_0         // (9_999+1) % 10_000 is 0
>    collection[10_000] = item_1        // (10_000+1) % 10_000 is 1
>    collection[10_001] = item_2
>    collection[10_002] = item_3     
>    collection[10_003] = item_4    
>    ...
>    collection[19_998] = item_9999      // (19_998+1) % 10_000 is 9_999
>    collection[19_999] = item_0         // (19_999+1) % 10_000 is 0
>    collection[20_000] = item_1
>    collection[20_001] = item_2
>    collection[20_002] = item_3
>    collection[20_003] = item_4
>    ...
> ```

<sup>above is NOT code</sup>

now note that `20_001 % 3` is `0` - so the third `item_2` will be picked; same true for `50_001 % 3` and `80_001 % 3`. So, actually that item is *added* 3 times to the *tree* (since it is a `Set`, only one instance is *kept*). At the end, one version of each *item* will be present in the result. Similar to `counter%3 == 1` or `counter%3 == 2` (basically the first code version posted in question.)

Lesson: checking that `item_2` is present or not, does NOT check if the condition *"returns true everytime"*.

---

*Better* test:

```
        ...
        int index = 0;  // DEBUG
        for(String item : this.collection) {
            if (counter%2==0) {
                System.out.println(index);  // DEBUG
                tree.add(item);
                counter = -1;
            }
            index += 1;  // DEBUG
            ...
```

<sup>above is not the **full** code, just showing idea for testing</sup>

---

Bonus: 
a `Set` does not *save* duplicates (*"A collection that contains no duplicate elements"*), in below snippet:

```
            if (!set.contains(item)) {
                set.add(item);
            }
```

the `if` is not necessary - this is already checked by `add()`